# Range hood ducting

Tags: kitchens

Can a 90 degree duct be placed immediately at the horizontal outlet (3.25 in x 10 in ) ?

If so, will it cause a certain level of "backdraft" whereby after the 90 degree elbow there is a 7 feet duct followed by a 3 feet duct and ended with a exterior side wall vent with damper ?

Should I be worried of doors forced back when the blower(s) is turned on ?

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. It is actually typical when a ducted range hood is installed on an interior wall, the duct HAS to go up or down inside the wall, so an elbow right at the unit is required.

Not sure what your "doors forced back" comment is about.

Comment: It is normal except when the exhaust duct goes straight up to the attic.

Comment: Yeah, or that.  .... :)